# Recursion using dates to pull transactions

Tags: sql, date, recursion

I am new to SQL and am having troubles with recursive dates.
I am basically trying to find out where our inventory is at a specific point in time and recursively do this for days after (depending on the time span).

**Example of Transactions_CTE:**

```
+------------------+-----------+--------------------+-----------------+-------+
| intTransactionID | intInvBID | varTransactionType |   dteDateTime   | intTo |
+------------------+-----------+--------------------+-----------------+-------+
|                1 | Item1     | I                  | 8/21/2014 11:03 |  1111 |
|                2 | Item1     | I                  | 8/23/2014 17:20 |  2222 |
|                3 | Item2     | I                  | 8/21/2014 11:03 |  1111 |
+------------------+-----------+--------------------+-----------------+-------+
```

**Wanted Result:**

```
+---------------+-----------+------------+-----------------+------------+
| dteTargetDate | intInvBID | varBarcode |   dteDateTime   | LocationID |
+---------------+-----------+------------+-----------------+------------+
| 8/22/2014     | Item1     |       8888 | 8/21/2014 11:03 |       1111 |
| 8/22/2014     | Item2     |       9999 | 8/21/2014 11:03 |       1111 |
| 8/23/2015     | Item1     |       8888 | 8/23/2014 17:20 |       2222 |
| 8/23/2015     | Item2     |       9999 | 8/21/2014 11:03 |       1111 |
+---------------+-----------+------------+-----------------+------------+
```

When I increase the range / change the endDate, I end up running into the following error:
The statement terminated. The maximum recursion 100 has been exhausted before statement completion.

I believe I am not doing the recursion correctly as @startDate does not change.

**Code Snippet:**

```
    DECLARE @startDate DATETIME, @endDate DATETIME
SELECT @startDate = '2014-08-22', @endDate = '2014-08-23'

;WITH BarcodeDetails_CTE (intInvBID, intInventoryID, varBarcode, varPartNo, varDescription)
    AS
    (
        -- All Barcodes with details
        SELECT 
            b.intInvBID,
            i.intInventoryID,
            b.varBarcode,
            i.varPartNo,
            i.varDescription
        FROM dbo.STG_Barcodes as b
        LEFT JOIN dbo.STG_Inventory as i
        ON b.intInventoryID = i.intInventoryID
        -- Optional Restriction
        WHERE i.varPartNo = 'A-01-040'
    ),
    Transactions_CTE (intTransactionID, intInvBID, varTransactionType, dteDateTime, intTo)
    AS
    (
        SELECT t.intTransactionID, t.intInvBID, t.varTransactionType, t.dteDateTime, t.intTo
        FROM dbo.STG_Transactions as t
        WHERE t.varTransactionType = 'I'
    ),
    Scans_CTE (intInvBID, varBarcode, dteTargetDate, dteDateTime, LocationID)
    AS
    (
        -- Anchor
        SELECT      bd.intInvBID,
                    bd.varBarcode,
                    @startDate as dteTargetDate,
                    t.dteDateTime,
                    t.intTo as LocationID
        FROM dbo.STG_Transactions as t
        INNER JOIN Transactions_CTE as tc
        ON t.intTransactionID = tc.intTransactionID AND t.dteDateTime <= @startDate 
        INNER JOIN BarcodeDetails_CTE as bd
        ON bd.intInvBID = t.intInvBID
        UNION ALL
        -- Recursive Member Definition
        SELECT      ls.intInvBID,
                    ls.varBarcode,
                    DATEADD(DAY,1,@startDate) as dteTargetDate,
                    ls.dteDateTime,
                    ls.LocationID
        FROM Scans_CTE as ls
        WHERE ls.dteTargetDate + 1 <= @endDate
    )
SELECT  rt.dteTargetDate,
        rt.intInvBID,
        rt.varBarcode,
        rt.dteDateTime,
        t.intTo as LocationID
FROM
    (SELECT ls.intInvBID,
            ls.varBarcode,
            ls.dteTargetDate,
            MAX(ls.dteDateTime) as dteDateTime
    FROM Scans_CTE as ls
    GROUP BY ls.dteTargetDate, ls.intInvBID, ls.varBarcode
    ) as rt
    INNER JOIN Transactions_CTE as t
    ON t.intInvBID = rt.intInvBID AND rt.dteDateTime = t.dteDateTime
ORDER BY dteTargetDate ASC;
```

Answer (score 0):

The default recursion value is 100. You can you special table hint in your recursive cte:

```
; WITH    cte
          AS ( SELECT   1 AS A
               UNION ALL
               SELECT   A + 1 AS A
               FROM     cte
               WHERE    A < 32767
             )

    SELECT  *
    FROM    cte  OPTION  ( MAXRECURSION 32767 );
```

> MAXRECURSION number Specifies the maximum number of recursions allowed
>   for this query. number is a nonnegative integer between 0 and 32767.
>   When 0 is specified, no limit is applied. If this option is not
>   specified, the default limit for the server is 100. When the specified
>   or default number for MAXRECURSION limit is reached during query
>   execution, the query is ended and an error is returned. Because of
>   this error, all effects of the statement are rolled back. If the
>   statement is a SELECT statement, partial results or no results may be
>   returned. Any partial results returned may not include all rows on
>   recursion levels beyond the specified maximum recursion level. For
>   more information, see WITH common_table_expression (Transact-SQL).

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181714.aspx

Comment: If I specify startDate = '2014-08-22' and endDate = '2014-08-24', it should only recurse twice correct?

Comment: @AeroChocolate, yes it should iterate only twice

Comment: Specifying the short date range (ex. 3 days), reaches the maximum recursion. I set MAXRECURSION to 32767. The statement terminated. The maximum recursion 32767 has been exhausted before statement completion. Any other tips?

Comment: @AeroChocolate, on first glance it should work. When you receive that error actually data is returned. Observe how dteTargetDate column is changed while iterations proceed.

Comment: I should have a restriction in the recursive member that is similar to 't.dteDateTime <= dteTargetTime' to get all transactions before the target date. However, I am not sure how to add that restriction within the recursive member. Perhaps the following: FROM Scans_CTE as ls
        WHERE ls.dteTargetDate + 1 <= @endDate AND t.dteDateTime <= dteTargetTime. However that would mean I would have to join the transactions table somehow for "t.dteDateTime."